# ActiveX error in VBA code to replace words in a Powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA code which is supposed to replace a word by another in a powerpoint. Nevertheless, when I try to run it I get the error 429 "ActiveX component can't create object" but I do not know why. Here is the code :

```
Sub pres()

    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
    Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    Dim myPres As Object
    Set myPres = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\PRESVBA\Pres.pptx")

    Dim sld As Slide
    Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(3)
    Dim shp As Shape

    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
    If shp.HasTextFrame Then
        If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
            shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "Montant", "Amount")
     End If
    End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Comment: What line does this error occur?  You do have powerpoint?

Comment: At the line Set sld = ActivePresentation.Slides(3), I do have Powerpoint, it opens the right file but I get the error

Comment: Do you have 3 slides in the powerpoint which you have opened ?

Comment: No, the code is supposed to change the words for slide number 3

Comment: You need to prefix this with `ActivePresentation.Slides(3)`  your `powerpointapp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are trying to update the slides from excel, if so please follow the steps

In the excel vba, go to Tools > References > check for Microsoft PowerPoint 16.0 Object Library (for Office 2019), you will find similar if the version of the Office is lower. Click OK

The code below

```
Sub pres()

    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
    Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")

    Dim myPres As Object
    Set myPres = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Personal\test\Presentation1.pptx")

    Dim sld As PowerPoint.Slide '<- change here
    Set sld = myPres.Slides(1) '<- number in brackets indicate the slide number
    Dim shp As PowerPoint.Shape '<- change here

    For Each shp In sld.Shapes
        If shp.HasTextFrame Then
            If shp.TextFrame.HasText Then
                shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Replace(shp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, "Montant", "Amount")
            End If
        End If
    Next shp
End Sub
```

Please mark it as an answer if it solves the pain :)